# Wicket DropDownChoice renderer issue

Tags: java, web, wicket, wicket-1.6

I have a problem with displaying options in a DropDownChoice (wicket 1.6).

```
DropDownChoice<Boolean> choice = new DropDownChoice<Boolean>("enabled", Arrays.asList(true, false), new ChoiceRenderer<Boolean>());
choice.setNullValid(true);
choice.setOutputMarkupId(true);

enabled.nullValid=Not selected
enabled.true=Yes
enabled.false=No
```

nullValid is displayed properly, true and fals  is not. How can I display yes and no instead of true and fals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom IChoiceRenderer *or* override #localizeDisplayValues() to return `true` and define values in your resource property files (possibly prepended with the component path):

```
true = yes
false = no
```